# run .hta as adminstrator

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Simple question: how do you run an `.hta` file as an admin? When I try running `runas /user:Grants-laptop\administrator computerinfo.hta` from command line, I get this error:

> RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - computerinfo.hta
>   193: computeinfo.hta is not a vailid Win32 application.

And there's no option when you right click it for running as an administrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTA (HTML Applications) should be associated with the Microsoft HTML Application Host (*mshta.exe*) program. Normally when you double-click the file through the Windows Explorer it automatically makes this association for you. When you are launching it from the command line you should do something like this:

```
runas /user:<user name> "mshta.exe <full path to HTA file>"
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this by default?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, but you can create a shortcut with the "mshta.exe <full path to HTA file>" as the target. After you have created the shortcut, you can go to Properties, select the Shortcut tab, click the Advanced button, and then choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I've ran into a problem when I run the command you show in your answer It doesn't find the file because my user name is my first name and my last name with a space in between and the command doesn't like that. I've tried `runas /user:grants-laptop\administrator "mshta.exe "c:\users\my fist lastname\desktop\program.hta"" but that doesn't work

Comment: Open a command prompt and change to your "C:\Users" directory. Run the "dir /X" command which will display short file names. You should see something that ends in a "~1" character for your home directory. Substitute that value in your path to the mshta file.

Comment: In Windows, you can almost always shorten a folder name to the first 6 characters, then add `~1`.  Exception:  When you have multiple folders with the same first 6 characters, then it becomes `~2`, `~3`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a commandlet.

Create a new text file

type into the text file (you may have to use quotes if the path to the .hta has spaces)
`%WINDIR%\system32\mshta.exe "FULLPATH_OF_HTA\FILENAME.hta"`

save the text file
change the extention from .txt to .cmd
now you can right click and run as admin or shift right click to run as other user.
you can also create shortcuts or change the icon to make it less generic looking.

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for me.

```
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /u:<domain>\<userid> "c:\windows\system32\mshta.exe """Full path to the hta\htaname.hta""""
```

Unfortunately there are a lot of quotation marks.

Comment: Didn't work for me no matter how many quotes I used.